# Solrj Questions for faceting and json resoponse

Tags: solrj, solr

I am trying to use solrj for my application, my code is given below,

```
        query.add("q", "simplify360");
        query.add("facet", "true");
        query.add("facet.range", "createdOnGMTDate");
        query.add("facet.range.start", "2010-08-01T00:00:00Z+330MINUTES");
        query.add("facet.range.end", "2011-05-31T00:00:00Z+330MINUTES");
        query.add("facet.range.gap", "+1DAY");
        //query.add("wt","json");
        //query.add("wt.mime-type","application/json");


        System.err.println(query.toString());
```

The code executes fine and when i execute the url on solr server, i get the following result for faceting,

```
        <lst name="facet_counts"><lst name="facet_queries"/>
        <lst name="facet_fields"/>
        <lst name="facet_dates"/>
        <lst name="facet_ranges">
        <lst name="createdOnGMTDate">
        <lst name="counts">
        <int name="2010-01-01T00:00:00Z">0</int>
        <int name="2010-01-02T00:00:00Z">0</int>
        <int name="2010-01-03T00:00:00Z">0</int>
        <int name="2010-01-04T00:00:00Z">0</int>
        <int name="2010-01-05T00:00:00Z">0</int>
        <int name="2010-01-06T00:00:00Z">0</int
        </lst>
        <str name="gap">+1DAY</str>
        <date name="start">2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</date>
        <date name="end">2011-05-31T00:00:00Z</date>
        </lst>
        </lst>
        </lst>
        </response>
```

1) How can i retrieve these values in java,

2) Also if there is anyway i can convert the json response to the json java object

Regards,

Rohit

Answer (score 1):

Using SOLRJ API, you can use following code:

```
QueryResponse rsp = server.query(query); // you issue the query and get resuls
Map<String, Integer> fq = rsp.getFacetQuery(); // this returns facetQuery part of response
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: nope no luck.. shows and empty map which the XML response shows results